# How to split a string into two parts?

Tags: python, string, string-length, divide, chunks

I am doing python exercises but I am stuck at one.

A string is divided in two parts(two new strings): part1 and part2.

If the length of the string is equal, then the two parts have to be equal as well.

E.g. `'Help' = 'He' and 'lp'`

If the length of the string is not equal, then the extra letter is assigned to part1.

E.g. `'Hello' = 'Hel' and 'lo'`

The exercise I am working on takes in two strings. I need to cut both these strings and then concatenate them in the following manner:

`<String1 Part1> + <String2 Part2>`

`<String2 Part1> + <String1 Part2>`

So if we have the words `card` and `plan` they become `caan` and `plrd`

So far all I can think of is:

```
def divide_strings(word1, word2):
    if len(word1)%2 > 0 or len(word2) %2 > 0:

    else len(word1) %2 == 0 or len(word2) %2 == 0:
```

I know I'm far from done, but I could really use a few hints in the right direction.
My brain is stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for algorithm advice or advice on how to concatenate/split strings?

Answer (score 2):

You said hint -- so

The important thing in dividing the string is trying to figure out where to cut this string.

Consider this assignment

```
x = len(s) // 2

if len(s) is 0 or 1, x will be 0
if len(s) is 2 or 3, x will be 1
if len(s) is 4 or 5, x will be 2
```

In all cases, x will be the number of characters you want assigned to part2

Look up string slicing and note that it can take a negative index to count from the end of a string

ADDED

Also, I notice you examples do not seem to match your problem statement.

I.e., if the original string is "card", I would expect the result below based on your problem statement. Obviously, your show a different expected result -- probably a good idea to double check things.

a/ca b/rd

Comment: his example is accurate. He takes in two words, then takes first part of first word and concatanates it with the end of the second word. And same thing with the first part of the second word with the second part of the first word.

Comment: Thanks -- Maybe it is correct. When I read his problem definition and I think it seems to indicate that what I suggested may be the intended result, which is why I suggested "seem to be" a mismatch and that OP double check. I.e., some of this is unclear -- clarity of though is always a good first step when writing code or writing about code.

Comment: I've tried making his explanation a little bit clearer ;) Either way, your answer should help.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is ceiling division:

```
>>> w = 'hello'
>>> split = -( ( -len(w) )//2 )
>>> split
3
>>> p1, p2 = w[:split], w[split:]
>>> p1
'hel'
>>> p2
'lo'
```

This is what split is:

1. Take the len of the word (5)
2. Take the negative of it (-5)
3. Do Python's normal floor division, (-5//2 == -3)
4. Then take the negative of that result, (3)

So do put this in a function:

```
def splitword(w):
    split = -((-len(w))//2)
    return w[:split], w[split:]
```

and

```
>>> splitword('help')
('he', 'lp')
>>> splitword('hello')
('hel', 'lo')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should help you out doing what you want. I don't have a python interpretter installed, so I couldn't in fact test this.

```
def splitword(w):
    split = -((-len(w))//2)
    return w[:split], w[split:]

part1a, part2a = splitword('card')
part1b, part2b = splitword('plan')

newword1 = part1a + part2b
newword2 = part1b + part2a
```